# Oralce Where clouse in IN Query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Emp_id, sal, age, exp
1        2   21   9
2        2   21   9
3        2   22   9
4        2   33   9
5        2   33   10


select sum(sal) from emp_table where age in (21,22,33,...);

Need to add some condition 
for age 21 No condition
for age 22 No condition
for age 33 exp > 10;
```

required output : sum(sal): 8
How can i achieve this in single query in oracle

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Why is that IN so important?

Comment: age parameter is dynamic thats why

Comment: Add one a row with age 22 and exp = 10 to the sample data, and adjust the result (if needed.)

Comment: Since you're asking so many times despite all the answers, no, you cannot do what you want only using an IN condition.

Comment: What if i dont know how many age will come to query? age = 21 or age = 22 or age = 33; will not work

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(sal) 
FROM emp_table 
WHERE age IN (21, 22) OR
(age = 33 AND exp > 10);
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition can be rewritten into the following form:

```
select sum(sal) 
from emp_table 
where age = 21 or age = 22 or age = 33;
```

Therefore, if you need to add any subsequent conditions to each `age` expression then you add it into parenthesis and use `AND` for example like this

```
select sum(sal) 
from emp_table 
where age = 21 or 
      age = 22 or 
      (age = 33 AND exp > 10);
```

EDIT: if you want to keep IN then I would do the following:

```
SELECT sum(sal) 
FROM emp_table 
WHERE age IN (21, 22) OR
      (age = 33 AND exp > 10);
```

Comment: can we do this using IN query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the IN statement with something in the line of:

```
select sum(sal) from emp_table where (age = 21 AND some_condition) OR age = 22 OR (age = 33 AND exp>10)
```

Comment: can we do this using IN query?